# How to restrict access between days and times?

Tags: php, date, time, visible

I like to add php-script for only allowing posts, comment between these days and times:

```
Monday-Friday: 09.00 - 19.00
Saturday: 10.00-15.00
```

All other times the post function shall not be available. Any idea in how I do that?

Started with this but then I realized I need days as well:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); // NDT 
$startTime = '09:00'; //opening hours starts
$endTime = '14:00'; //closing hours 
$time = new DateTime($startTime); 
$time1 = date_format($time, 'H:i'); 
$time = new DateTime($endTime); 
$time2 = date_format($time, 'H:i');

"Today is " . $current =date("H:i") . "<br>";

if ($current > $time1 && $current < $time2) {
     echo 'The pposting is closed from 13.00 - 09.00. Sorry for the Inconvenience.'; }
else{
   echo "It's open";
}
```

Comment: Please you show us what code you have tried using to achieve this.

Comment: Started with thjis but then I realized I need days as well.<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); // NDT
$startTime = '09:00'; //opening hours starts
$endTime = '14:00'; //closing hours
$time = new DateTime($startTime);
$time1 =  date_format($time, 'H:i'); 
$time = new DateTime($endTime);
$time2 =  date_format($time, 'H:i');
"Today is " . $current =date("H:i") . "<br>";
if ($current > $time1 && $current < $time2)
{
echo 'The pposting is closed from 13,00 - 09,00. Sorry for the Inconvenience.';
}else{

echo "It's open";
}
?>

Comment: it's better to add code to the question. it will be more readable

Comment: Yes, of course. But now I am looking for the code so :-)

Comment: @misterbister Please edit your questions instead of posting relevant parts in a comment.

Comment: ok, sorry. I sw you did that for me in my Q. My first Q here so I hope you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function to set the default timezone used by all date/time functions. (taken from the manual)

To specify the format you want from [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can use the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method. The characters used in this example for the format method are taken from [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

What you could do is get the day of the week by using the 'N' for the format and then check if it is a weekday or Saturday.

> N     ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in
>   PHP 5.1.0)    1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

Then check using the start/end times for the weekday or Saturday if it is open or closed and display your message.

For displaying the message I've used [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Maybe this setup can help you:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
function displayAllowPostsMessage($dateTime)
{
    $weekdayStartTime = new DateTime('09:00');
    $weekdayEndTime = new DateTime('19:00');
    $saturdayStartTime = new DateTime('10:00');
    $saturdayEndTime = new DateTime('15:00');
    $templateOpen = "It's %s and we are open!";
    $templateClosed = "It's %s and the posting are only allowed between %s - %s. Sorry for the Inconvenience.";
    $dayOfTheWeek = intval($dateTime->format('N'));
    $message = "It's closed on sunday.";

    // On a weekday
    if ($dayOfTheWeek < 6) {
        $isOpen = $dateTime > $weekdayStartTime && $dateTime < $weekdayEndTime;
        $message = sprintf(
            $templateOpen,
            $dateTime->format('l H:i')
        );
        if (!$isOpen) {
            $message = sprintf(
                $templateClosed,
                $dateTime->format('l H:i'),
                $weekdayStartTime->format("H:i"),
                $weekdayEndTime->format("H:i")
            );
        }
    }

    // On a saturday
    if ($dayOfTheWeek === 6) {
        $isOpen = $dateTime > $saturdayStartTime && $dateTime < $saturdayEndTime;
        $message = sprintf(
            $templateOpen,
            $dateTime->format('l H:i')
        );
        if (!$isOpen) {
            $message = sprintf(
                $templateClosed,
                $dateTime->format('l H:i'),
                $saturdayStartTime->format("H:i"),
                $saturdayEndTime->format("H:i")
            );
        }
    }
    echo $message;
}

displayAllowPostsMessage(new DateTime());
```

[Demo with added debug code to test different days](https://3v4l.org/FDEeR)

Comment: @misterbister You are welcome. If this helped solving your problem you can always consider marking the answer as accepted. Cheers!